# How to use reduce to transform an array into an object?

Tags: javascript, reduce, arrow-functions

Thanks to another SO thread, I have managed to transform an array of arrays into an object thanks to `reduce()`. However, I don't understand why it works.

Could someone please explain to me why I can't only write => acc[key] = value, {} ? This syntax makes sense to me. But it returns `21`! It only works if I add `,acc` between my object assignation and my starting value `{}`. Also, ESLint claims it is an `unexpected use of comma operator`.

```js
const myArray = [["player1", 30], ["player2", 21]];
const obj = myArray.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {});

console.log("obj : ", obj);
```

I have also written this. It works well as well, but I'm still wondering why the first script works:

```js
const myArray = [["player1", 30], ["player2", 21]];
const obj = myArray.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => Object.assign(acc, {[key]: value}),{});

console.log("obj : ", obj);
```

Comment: Because  adding `, acc` will return `acc` object. only `acc[key] = value` will return `value` not `acc`.

Comment: The second snippet have error

Comment: you always have to accumulate into you acc otherwise you are just returning the one value it's like having a for loop and returning the last value of it instead of aggregating all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `reduce()` you need to return the accumulator `acc` from the callback

Second thing you need to understand is implicit return. When you use arrow function `=>` without `{}` and `return` the value after `=>` becomes the return value of the function.

Another thing you need to understand is comma operator. When you use comma operator between two or more expressions it evaluates to the last one.

```js
console.log(("first", "second", "third"))
```

In the above snippet the whole expression `("first", "second", "third")` evaluates to `"third"`.

Same happens in ur case `(acc[key] = value, acc)` evaluates to `acc`.

```js
const myArray = [["player1", 30], ["player2", 21]]
const toObj = myArray.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
})
console.log(toObj)
```

> Could someone please explain to me why I can't only write => acc[key] = value, {} ?

I mentioned above when you use `reduce()` you need to `return` `acc` from ur function. So then you use the above way `acc[key] = value` gets returned from each iteration. and `acc[key] = value` will always evaluate to `value` so the whole reduce method returns the last `value` which is `21`